# Check if any of multiple conditions are true in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cancan, cancancan

I have the following Ruby conditional:

```
<% if can? :read, %w(policy journey crash user).map(&:to_sym) %>
```

Which I want to translate to: if the user has read permissions for any of the resources in the array.

However it always returns false. How can I fix it?

I don't want to do:

```
if can? :read, :policy || can? :read, :journey || etc...
```

Comment: I don't think we can answer you without knowing what the `can?` method looks like...

Comment: @Anthony https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L62

Comment: `%w(policy journey crash user).map(&:to_sym)` would be better as `%i(policy journey crash user)` in newer Rubies.

Comment: @muistooshort I am using `%w`...

Comment: `%w(...)` produces an array of strings which you then convert to symbols, `%i(...)` produces an array of symbols directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can.

[Enumerable#`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) is exactly what you're looking for:

```
<% if %i(policy journey crash user).any? { |action| can? :read, action } %>
```

The above will return `true` only if `can read any action`.

Note, I used `%i` instead of `%w`. It gives you array of symbols.

Comment: It seems like OP wants to see `any?` instead of `all?`, but does not want to write `can? :read, :policy || can? :read, :journey || etc...`, because it is not DRY.