# Checking multiple actions in CanCanCan can? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I would like to be able to check multiple actions in a given `can?` method (in the controller or view).

The docs (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities) show the following syntax:

```
can? :destroy, @project
```

This works fine but I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
can? [:destroy, :another_action], @project
```

This doesn't work, it just returns `false` even though both of the actions (`:destroy` and `:another_action`) called individually return true.

Of course I could do something like the following but it's not a very concise and would get unwieldily very fast (if I needed to check more than two actions)

```
(can? :destroy, @project && can? :another_action, @project)
```

How can I check multiple actions in with a single `can?` call?

Comment: You can enumerate and check each one per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656017/728379